# Why "Date"data type having longer run times versus varchar date?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a sales table in MySQL Workbench, and 2 columns that contain identical dates, except one of the columns is a date with varchar data type (hence - 12/31/2023) and the other column is a date data type (hence - 2023-12-31). Both are indexed in the same way.

When I run a query like, SELECT sum(sales_col), Date_col WHERE Date > 12/15/2023. the DATE date type version runs at least 5 times slower than when I run the query using the VARCHAR date. I would think the DATE data type is designed to be the most efficient method here. Am I missing something?? I would essentially like to discontinue to varchar date, but this is holding me back.

Comment: Are you really missing quotes around `12/15/2023`?

Comment: It needs to be quoted, and the format needs to be `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `MM/DD/YYYY`

Comment: When you write `12/15/2023` without quotes, it's arithmetic: divide 12 by 15, then divide that by 2023.

Comment: Sorry, I was just being hypothetical. I do use quotes for each version, as such: SELECT sum(sales_col), Date_col WHERE Date > '12/15/2023' (FOR VARCHAR) ; SELECT sum(sales_col), Date_col WHERE sql_date > '2023-12-15' (FOR DATE). It is not even possible to run the query without the quotes involved.

Comment: Do you have an index on the column?

Comment: It would be best if you posted actual table schemas, the precise query, and the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: _"Am I missing something??"_ Yes, they are completely different queries with potentially very different result sets, depending on the data. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77456209/edit) with the two complete queries that you are comparing, the [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan) output for each of them, and the DDL for the table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;`).

Comment: Have a look at this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ge-Jft7T) and hopefully something will _"click"_.

Comment: *Am I missing something?* Of course. `WHERE varchar_column > '12/15/2023'` will skip the row with the value `'01/01/2024'` whereas `WHERE date_column > '2023-12-15'` will include the row with the same value `'2024-01-01'` into the output. Also, when you compare two string operands they are compared immediately whereas the comparing of varchar and date needs in datatype convertion.

Comment: `DATE` datatype might run 5 times slower but it's returning more row results than the `VARCHAR` datatype. Am I wrong?

Comment: From a table of 5 years of dates, filtering a string column returns 84 rows, but the same filter applied to a date column returns 1477 rows.  Also look at the explain plans - both use indexes - see https://dbfiddle.uk/t76y5bKL - your question needs more detail.